# Sending Messages to a rabbit mq broker topic inside a GCP cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, rabbitmq

What would be the optimal way to send messages to a rabbit mq topic from the firebase cloud function.

We need to send messages to a broker topic upon fire store write/update trigger. Currently for every trigger we are connecting to the queue and closing the connection on defer(golang).

Is it costly/Memory intensive to open and close connection on every trigger?

If so,What are the options available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [best practices in Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities) is

> **Do not start background activities**. Background activity is anything that happens after your function has terminated. A function invocation finishes once the function returns or otherwise signals completion, such as by calling the callback argument in Node.js background functions. Any code run after graceful termination cannot access the CPU and will not make any progress.

Having each call on each CF execution is the best way to avoid anti pattern practices.
About the costs, the [pricing of CFs](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) is a good place where you can take a look at.

On the other hand, you might want to take a look into [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub):

> Pub/Sub is an asynchronous messaging service that decouples services that produce events from services that process events.

> You can use Pub/Sub as messaging-oriented middleware or event ingestion and delivery for streaming analytics pipelines.

If trying to reduce costs you can also check [PubSub lite](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/choosing-pubsub-or-lite)

> To reduce costs, you can use Pub/Sub Lite. Pub/Sub Lite is a zonal service for messaging systems with predictable traffic patterns. If you publish 1 MiB-1 GiB of messages per second, Pub/Sub Lite might be an order of magnitude cheaper.

Here is an example of [Creating a Cloud Function to publish messages to Pub/Sub](https://medium.com/@chandrapal/creating-a-cloud-function-to-publish-messages-to-pub-sub-154c2f472ca3), the code should looks as follows:

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
def hello_world(request):
    try:
        testAttribute = request.get_json().get('test')
        topic_name = 'projects/badshah-project/topics/pubsub-publisher'.format(
            project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
            topic='pubsub-publisher',
        )
        publisher.publish(topic_name, b'', testAttribute=testAttribute)
        return f"OK"
    except:
        return f"Not OK"
```